# Is it possible to import the pyomo model solution in another .py file in the same directory

Tags: optimization, constraint, pyomo

I have a model say **cost.py** as follows:

```
import statements
def mymodel():
     model = ConcreteModel()

     model.var =  #Some variables
     moddel.par=   #Some variables
     model.const = #Some Constraints

     model.obj1 = Objective(expr=(model.var * model.par)+(model.var2 * model.par1), sense=minimize)

     status = SolverFactory('glpk')
     results = status.solve(model)
     assert_optimal_termination(results)
     model.display()
mymodel()
```

Now I have another file in the same directory say **test.py.**

I want to use the model in cost.py and its **variable, parameters and results** in test.py. I am doing it because I want to write a seperate *testing function* in the **test.py** to check whether my **cost.py** model is functioning as it should be or not? *Please guide me on how to import the variable, parameters and result.*

Comment: You can import `mymodel` function into test.py. Your variable, parameters, and result are bound to `mymodel` function. If you want to import those, I suggest you create a class, then make what you want attributes of those class (e.g. `self.variable`). Then you can pass the instance of your class to test.py

Comment: Thank you @EhsanK for such a prompt response. Do you mean this way?

`import mymodel
  class Testclass:
         def __init__(self, var1):
              self.var1 = var1
              self.param=par1
       def cost(self):
              return self.var1 * self.par1`
Can you elaborate what do you mean by passing the instance to test.py

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way I can think of.
In your `cost.py`, you have something like the following (I'm assuming you import `pyomo` or whatever package you need):

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # whatever you need to pass to the class
        self.model = ConcreteModel()
        self.model.var = ...
        self.model.par = ...
        self.model.const = ...
        self.results = None  # just a placeholder. It'll be populated later
        # just an example. You don't need to define all of them in init method.
        # To give an example, I define objectives in a different method

    def set_objective(self):
        self.model.obj1 = Objective(expr=(self.model.var * self.model.par)+(self.model.var2 * self.model.par1), sense=minimize)
        status = SolverFactory('glpk')
        self.results = status.solve(self.model)
        assert_optimal_termination(self.results)
        self.model.display()
```

Now, in `test.py`, you can have a function called `test_func()`. It can be defined as follows:

```
from cost import MyModel

def test(mm):
    # mm here is the instance of MyModel class that I passed to test_func
    var = mm.model.var
    par = mm.model.par
    result = mm.results
    # do whatever you need to do here
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mm = MyModel()  # pass whatever arguments you need to initialize the class
    mm.set_objective()  # after a successful run, `mm.results` will have values
    test(mm)
```

Something like this should do the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The simplest thing you can do is to change `mymodel()` to return the model that it creates, then store that object at the module scope.  That is:

```py
def mymodel():
    # ....
    model.display()
    return model

model = mymodel()
```

Then, in `test.py`, you can get the model using `from cost import model`.

In addition, you will likely find it very helpful to separate the generation of the model from the invocation of the solver.  That is, I would recommend having two functions in `cost.py`:

```py
import statements
def create_mymodel():
     model = ConcreteModel()

     model.var =  #Some variables
     moddel.par=   #Some variables
     model.const = #Some Constraints

     model.obj1 = Objective(expr=(model.var * model.par)+(model.var2 * model.par1), sense=minimize)
     return model

def solve_mymodel(model):
     status = SolverFactory('glpk')
     results = status.solve(model)
     assert_optimal_termination(results)
     model.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = create_mymodel()
    solve_mymodel(model)
```

Finally, note the use of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard: this lets you still use `cost.py` as a standalone script, but makes testing easier as it will not generate or solve the model when you are importing the `cost.py` module in other contexts (e.g., from `test.py`).  If you go down this route, your `test.py` module might look like:

```py
import cost

model = cost.create_mymodel()
# test some properties of the model itself 
# (e.g., number of constraints, objectives, evaluations at specific points, etc)

cost.solve_mymodel(model)
# test the solution
```